# ¿Cómo puedo guardar una imagen a firebase storage y que la dirección de descarga se guarde en la database?

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

buen día. Soy nuevo con Android Studio y estoy realizando un proyecto en donde se deben guardar datos al igual que imágenes.
Este es el método que tengo para agregar datos, pero quisiera saber como puedo implementar un botón que abra la galería y el usuario pueda seleccionar una imagen y posteriormente subirla a firebase storage, y al momento de subirla, la dirección de descarga se guarde junto con los demás datos que se ingresan en los edit text para que posteriormente lo muestre todo en un recycler view.

```
private void cargarDatosFirebase(String responsables, String especie, String monitor, String grupo, String email, String fecha, String escuela) {
    Map<String, Object> datosArboles = new HashMap<>();


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    if (responsables.equals("") | especie.equals("") | monitor.equals("") | grupo.equals("") |email.equals("") | fecha.equals("") |escuela.equals("")  ){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Debe llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {


        datosArboles.put("responsables", responsables);
        datosArboles.put("especie", especie);
        datosArboles.put("monitor", monitor);
        datosArboles.put("grupo", grupo);
        datosArboles.put("email", email);
        datosArboles.put("fecha", fecha);
        datosArboles.put("escuela", escuela);


        mRootReference.child("Arboles").child(userID).child("Arbol Registrado").push().setValue(datosArboles);

        if (datosArboles != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Datos registrados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mEditTextResponsables.setText(" ");
            mEditTextEspecie.setText(" ");
            mEditTextMonitor.setText(" ");
            mEditTextEmail.setText(" ");
            mEditTextFecha.setText(" ");
            mEditTextEscuela.setText(" ");
            mEditTextGrupo.setText(" ");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando subes un archivo a Firebase Storage tenes 2 callbacks, `onSuccess` y el `onFailure`, dentro del primer callback te dice que se pudo subir exitosamente tu imagen/archivo.

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("tu_referencia");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

   uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw task.getException();
            }

            // continuar con el task para obtener la url de descarga
            return ref.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                String downloadURL = downloadUri.toString();
                 mRootReference.child("Arboles").child(userID).child("Arbol Registrado").child(idArbol).child("url_foto").setValue(downloadURL); //seteamos la url de la imagen en el database
            } else {
                // Manejo de errores
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
```

Te recomiendo que leas la documentacion oficial donde detalla bien como debes hacer el proceso

[Sube archivos en Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=es)

Comment: Me sale un error en la parte de getDownloadUrl()

Comment: ahi te actualice el codigo, si te funciona podrias marcar la respuesta como correcta ? gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias Gastón, me has ayudado bastante. Ya la marqué como correcta.

Comment: Y ¿cómo podria obtener el "idArbol" para guardar el link dentro del mismo lugar que los datos?